# Quickly filter an image with a bank of Gaussian filters - OpenCV

Tags: opencv, filtering

I am essentially doing an oriented Gaussian Blur on an image. However, each pixel has it's own orientation. Because of this I have to do a manual convolution. This part of the algorithm is very slow.

Is there any way I can manipulate the filter engine in any way to convolve the image with a different filter at each point instead of doing a multiplication with the rotated filter and summing for each pixel? Perhaps this is not the correct approach but it is what crossed my mind. The hope is to get much closer to the speed of a traditional gaussian blur instead of being many many times slower.

Maybe I could split the image n times where n represents possible orientations and parallelize the filtering. The results of each could be combined back into one image.

Thoughts?

Comment: maybe make a code image with the directions of the kernels, with one large "filter" buffer containing all the filters with size n*n*n_directions, and make a custom filterengine that uses the code image to look up the filter needed?

Comment: also, I'm not sure making it MT will help at all, your memory bandwidth will be a mess. you can probably use the gpu as the architecture is more suited for parallel reads of data though.

Comment: I have n filters alongside a "code" image where each pixel represents the orientation. This aligns with the number of filters. I am not familiar with using filter engine. Do you know how to manipulate it to implement the method you described?